# Antlr generates broken C# code, missing variable name in declaration

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I have an grammar for a template language.

I created this for Antlr 3.2 and CSharp2 target and have it working.

Now I try to change to antlr 3.4 and CSharp3 target (have tried CSharp2 also) and I get a strange error in the Parser in a synpred function.

Several variable declarations are missing the variable name:

```
IToken  = default(IToken)
```

Some also have th wrong type

```
void  = default(void);
```

should be

```
AstParserRuleReturnScope<CommonTree, IToken>  = default(AstParserRuleReturnScope<CommonTree, IToken>);
```

Have any one seen this before and what could be causing this.

The grammar is the same that was working before.

Unfortunately I cannot share the grammar and I have not had time to create a test grammar that causes the same error.

I can of course fix the errors manually and the code works but it's a bit tiresome to have to go through the code after generation fixing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem by using the [native .NET version](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr3CSharpReleases) of the ANTLR code generation tool (Antlr3.exe) instead of the Java version. Specifically, antlr-dotnet-tool-3.4.1.9004.7z worked for me, whereas antlr-3.4-complete-no-antlrv2.jar did not.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late accept, missed this after vacation.

Comment: Actually we resolved it in another way, I hand coded my own lexer/parser/interpreter ;)